# Connecting secondary ground with primary ground

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, emc

My system must be made of 2 DC/DC converters and a battery (safe voltage level). I already have a DC/DC converter that I bought on internet. It is the [following](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/RSD-30G-24?qs=Mv7BduZupUiyc0dQLww4MA%3D%3D&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAgK2qBhCHARIsAGACuzk-vtVNnjl65ZRNJ_QMuvwIfGBiNQlabmBalSLL2nAw1eMRMxnLfd4aAubpEALw_wcB). It is an isolated DC DC converter. I have to buy an other DC DC converter for having an other output voltage level. What I know is the ouputs of the 2 DC DC converter have to be referenced to the same ground. If I buy an isolated DC/DC converter I will have two connect the ground of the 2 isolated converter together. If I buy a non isolated DC converter, I will indirectly connect the "isolated" ground of my isolated DC DC converter to the primary side as I will connect the ground of my non isolated ground to my "isolated" ground.

Here are the schematics :

1st solution :

[image]

2nd solution :

[image]

What I do not know are the consequences of those 2 different architectures ? What is the best choice ? I know that the isolation will protect one side from the other. But is there any other consequences ? Do you think that it is possible to connect the primary ground and the secondary ground together of an isolated dc dc converter without consequences ? Also the load as to be well regulated. I am afraid of having more parasitics if the non isolated configuration is choosed as the ground of the board will share the current of the "secondary side" and also a bit of the current of the "primary side" in the non isolated solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown either arrangement will work, AND neither converter needs to be isolated.

Assume that eg the upper converteris +10V and the lower is +5V.
With all grounds connected the target board will see ground, +5V, +10V, regardless of whether the converters are isolated or not.
Assign a voltage to each wire to see that this is true.

However, if you used the lower diagram BUT connected the upper isolated converter ground to the +5V output of the lower non-isolated inverter, the   target board will now see: ground, +5V, +15V.
Assign a voltage to each wire to see that this is true.

Using one or two isolated converters offers more flexibility.
The only disadvantages are usually size and cost - and both those may be minimially different or zero.

One thing to watch is if high voltages are used - eg lower converter = 200V, upper isolated = 10V, then stacking them as above gives ground, 200V, 210V BUT the 10V converter insulation needs to be able to withstand the 200V offset above ground.